# Pure css drop down or jquery dropdown?

Tags: jquery, css

Which is the best way for making an drop down menu, pure CSS or jQuery?

I am interested which of the two has the best browser compatibility, which one creates less problems?

I want the menu to be supported in all major browsers, I can use all versions of CSS, I don't need fancy things from the menu I need it to be simple and clean and WORKING.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question. The real answer is: it depends.

Comment: If you can use css, but as stated it depends. What browsers are you supporting? Can you use CSS3? Do you need animation? Are you using javascript on your site regardless of the drop down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For CSS menus, you're stuck in mud with older browsers like IE6 and 7, if you need to support these, because they do not support the pseudo :hover attribute on elements typically desired as the target for a dropdown menu. They require Javascript to add the basic hover support.

If you are catering for modern browsers, then your final concern really is accessibility. If you poorly construct a menu and Users do not have Javascript enabled, then you have issues. If you use semantic markup and use tried & tested Dropdown menu techniques, like the ones @David Faux suggests, then you will be fine.

Some valid questions in the commentary though. I'd also add:

- Once your project is live, will you be able to update/maintain it at all? As new browser versions are released, problems can arise with both CSS and JS menus.
- Who will be maintaining the menu in the future, will they have the same or better experience than you?

I put my money on sturdy Javascript menus with semantic markup and commented code.

Comment: To answer to your questions, i will maintain the the project. The perspective ideas are welcome, thank you.

Comment: No probs, Dropdown menus have come a long way over the years, have fun picking a good one :D

Answer (score 0):

Suckerfish dropdowns are pretty cross-browser compliant. They do not use jQuery, but are prevalently used.
http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/

Aside from that, here are some good jQuery dropdown menus:
http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/

Comment: Superfish is a jquery plugin that improves upon Suckerfish and adds some nice gracefully degrading features http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/